# How to printf a char that always prints one column

Tags: c, printf

When I printf a char with %c format and the char is unprintable like '\0' then there is no column of printout.  Same if I use %1c.  Or %1.1c. Is there a way to force printf to output a column for '\0'?

I'm doing some large printf's and I want columns to match up.

Comment: You got this problem with other characters too? Or only with \0? In case of the latter, print `(c == '\0'?' ':c)`.

Comment: @Golez see my 2nd comment under George's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing you can do for printf. But you can use [isprint](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/isprint.3.asp) to filter the arguments of printf

```
printf("%c", (isprint(c) ? c : ' ' ));
```

Comment: Thx, George.  That works for me.  I tried to use a macro but couldn't make it work.  Got these messages:`subs.c:40: warning: too few arguments for format
subs.c:40: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
subs.c:40: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
`*** I'll never figure out mini-Markdown ***

Comment: I think that the macro didn't work because isprint is a macro and you can't nest macros.  (That's a guess.)  Now I'm using #define N(c) (c=='\0' ? '\\' : c) which prints a \ for a '\0'.  I like this because it's short to type and lets me see the terminating char on strings with no confusion over other non-printables.  I like this.

Answer (score 2):

How about writing

```
printf("%c",(c<' ')?' ':c);
```

You can easily put this in a `#define`.

Comment: bitmask, I'm giving you comment a +1 for suggesting a macro.  See my 2nd comment under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could change the character argument to

isgraph(c) ? c : ' '

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `isprint` function to check to see if the character is printable first.

```
if(isprint(c)) {
   printf("%c", c);
}
else {
   print("?");
}
```

Not sure what you plan on doing with non-printable characters though.